# How do I create an Ubuntu bootable disk img from the Ubuntu container?

Tags: boot, system-installation

Currently, I use a preseed file to get a new ubuntu install configured how I want. However, that requires booting up a VM, running through the installation, etc. Even if I use packer.io, it still is a slow process. Each error on install or post-install requires a restart, and is resource-demanding.

At the end of the process, I end up with an img (or vmdk or iso, pick your file format) that has a filesystem in it with all of the files in the right location.

Is there a way to get the same net result using a container? A good chunk of ubuntu is already available in the `ubuntu:16.04` image on docker hub. I can copy everything over to a mount volume. There are plenty of tools for creating the img itself and partitioning it to `/boot` (ext4), `/` (ext4), and EFI (FAT). So it is just a question of getting the correct files.

Is there a way to get the rest?

I did a `find / -xdev` in a container and in an installed VM and ran a diff. Got 56000 lines, the overwhelming majority of which are `/usr/src/linux-headers/`, followed by apt cache, dpkg, etc.

I can run `grub-install`, to place grub where and how I want it. What about all of the `/dev`, `/etc/apparmor`, `/etc/init/`, `/etc/init.d/`, `/etc/initramfs-tools/`, `/etc/rc_.d/`, `/etc/ssl/`, and especially all of the `/lib/firmware/`, `/lib/modules/`, `/lib/systemd/` for `dbus`, `dev`, `initrd` and other boot services?